# Celery: update state of task when using classes

Tags: python, celery, python-3.5

Hi i'm trying to update the state of a method which is executed as a task:

As described in : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    @celery.task(filter=task_method)
    def add(self):
         self.a += 10

         for i in range(10):
             self.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={
                 "current": i, "total": 10, "status": "Sleeping"
             })


         return {"current": 100, "total": 100, "status": "Complete."}



a = A()
a.add.delay()
```

Which gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'update_state'
```

Which seems logical to me since A does not inherit from task, so it hasn't got the "update_task" method.

**Question**: How do i update the state of an task when using method based tasks ???

**Update**:
As described in the comments below, updating the status of a task which is
not bound is impossible, therefore the celery.contrib.methods way of defining methods as tasks is not usable in my example.

Comment: Don't you still need to bind the bask?

Comment: @erip The duplicate you posted describes another way of implementing method based tasks i think. I'm referring to updating the state of tasks implemented as described in:  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

Comment: Try `bind=True` in the decorator; i.e., `@celery.task(bind=True, filter=task_method)`

Comment: bind=True in the decorator gives: TypeError: add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: I really don't think what you're trying to do is going to work like this. I think the method prescribed by the dupe I posted is the way to do it. Updating relies on binding the task. Binding the task gives the task a `self`, which you are currently mixing with the class A's `self`.

Comment: I understand the dupe's way of doing it. But the contrib's docs describe this way of defining methods-based tasks. The task itself is handled correctly by Celery. When i call a.add.delay()   without the  update_state in my method it works. So from what i make out of this is that the celery.contrib.methods way of defining method-based tasks doesn't support updating task-state???

Comment: This is exactly what I'm saying -- **updates require the task to be bound**. Without binding the task, you can't update the status.

Comment: From the docs: _The bind argument means that the function will be a “bound method” so that you can access attributes and methods on the task type instance._

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do it like that:

```
from celery import Celery, current_task

celery = Celery()

class A:
  @celery.task(filter=task_method)
  def add(self):
    # ...
    current_task.update_state('PROGRESS', meta={...})

a = A()
a.add.delay()
```

Notice that I use `current_task` proxy instead of the `self` variable (which, in contrary to class methods, denotes *current task* in bound Celery tasks).

Alternatively (didn't check that but probably it should work as well), you may be able to bind class method task as well:

```
class A:
  @celery.task(filter=task_method, bind=True)
  def add(self, task):
    task.update_state('PROGRESS', meta={...})
```

Probably you'll have to exchange `self` and `task` arguments for them to work properly, not sure about that.

BTW, it seems that `celery.contrib.methods` [was removed](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#unscheduled-removals) in Celery 4.0.